# Sinatra: Repeating code during CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I'm fairly new to Sinatra (like < 5 hours ago) and I'm noticing a pattern on my POSTs (and the other keywords too)

```
post '/pageant' do
pageant = Pageant.new(params)
if pageant.save
    json_status 201, 'good'
    Pageant.last.to_json
else
    json_status 412, 'fail'
end
end
```

I have other models: for the candidates, the judges, the categories, the scores, etc. I feel like I'm going to be writing this multiple times: Get the parameters, attempt to save, if everything is valid (according to DataMapper), send a 201 or 200 and return the last, else throw an error (json_status is a method that throws an error status and error code). The same happens for DELETE: "check if deleted, if deleted send OK, if not send error"... How do I DRY this thing? I'd definitely appreciate the help.

Comment: Just want to comment that, depending on your overall infrastructure (number of Web instances/workers, concurrency of your DB & driver), when going `Model.save` then `Model.last` there can be a race condition where if another thread/process creates a new record in between those calls then `Model.last` can return the other record, which can lead to all sorts of confusion or can constitute a security/privacy breach.

Comment: +1 and to add to @AlistairIsrael IMO this is almost in place. As app grows you may constraints on save and alternate flows for validation failure or other types of failures. You could wrap such calls at Model itself.

Comment: @AlistairIsrael okay I will keep that in mind... I think I heard that in the Coursera course on Pattern-Based Software Architecture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this, one function for the different models.
The splat I am pertaining to is this. I am not sure if this is the right way to do this, as I am not that good in Regex so I made what I can with something like an in_array. How can we improve this?

Before hook

```
before do
@models = ['pageant', 'round', 'category', 'candidate', 'judge', 'score', 'setting']
content_type :json
end
```

Post for the different models

```
post '/:model/?' do

model_name = params[:captures].first
params.delete("splat")
params.delete("captures")
params.delete("model")


if @models.include? model_name
    model_class = Module.const_get(model_name.capitalize)

    if model_class.new(params).save
        json_status 201, model_class.last.to_json
        model_class.last.to_json
    else
        json_status 412, 'fail'
    end
else
    json_status 412, 'fail'
end
```

end

Answer (score 2):

Define a regex based route and then dynamically instantiate the model object based on the HTTP path. This solution assumes that the path name and the model name will be the same.

```
post %r{/([\w]+)} do
  model_name = params[:captures].first.capitalize
  save_and_return(model_name, params)
end

def save_and_return(model_name, params)
  model_class = Module.const_get(model_name)
  model = model_class.new(params)
  if model.save
    json_status 201, 'good'
    model.last.to_json # Keep in mind AlistairIsrael's comment!
  else
    json_status 412, 'fail'
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey man, I tried this, for the most part it is working, but why does a splat get included? What happens is that I have to delete the splat

Comment: Which splat are you referring to?

Comment: Avilay I put in an answer, can you check it out? I cannot format my code well in this comment so I just made an answer. I really appreciate the help

Comment: Oh ok, I see. That is Sinatra adding those keys to the params hash whenever the route is a regex pattern. From the Sinatra README page (http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) - "Route patterns may also include splat (or wildcard) parameters, accessible via the params[:splat] array:". Ideally your model's initialize method should just take the keys from the params hash that it needs and ignore the rest. That way you don't have to delete any keys like "splat" in the params hash.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method

```
post '/pageant' do
  save_method(params)
end

post '/other' do
  save_method(params)
end

def save_method(params)
  pageant = Pageant.new(params)
  if pageant.save
   json_status 201, 'good'
   Pageant.last.to_json
  else
   json_status 412, 'fail'
  end
end
```